# Can onChange = {this.nameHandler} invoke nameHandler = (event) =>{}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, eventhandler

Below is code snippets that works,

State-

```
state = {
        name : '',
        age : ''
    }
```

onChangeHandler-

```
nameHandler = (event) =>{
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    }
```

UI-

```
<input type = "text" onChange = {this.nameHandler} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

---

But why does the following not work?

State-

```
state = {
        name : '',
        age : ''
    }
```

onChangeHandler-

```
nameHandler = (event) =>{
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    }
```

UI-

```
<input type = "text" onChange = {(event) =>this.nameHandler} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

Not even the following,

```
state = {
        name : '',
        age : ''
    }

onChangeHandler-

nameHandler(event){
        this.setState({name: event.target.value})
    }
```

UI-

```
<input type = "text" onChange = {(event) =>this.nameHandler} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

I understand the reason for my question is lacking knowledge in arrow function theory.

Please share detailed reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the second example

```
<input type = "text" onChange = {(event) =>this.nameHandler} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

Here you are not calling the original function. Here is just a wrapper function which returns another function. Events handlers are not effected by the return value.

```
<input type = "text" onChange = {(event) =>this.nameHandler(event)} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

change it following to call the function onChange: `this.nameHandler` --> `this.nameHandler()`

```
  <input type = "text" onChange = {(event) =>this.nameHandler(event)} value = {this.state.name}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the event.target.value in a variable like this

```
nameHandler = (event) =>{
    let {value=''} = event.target;
        this.setState({name: value});
}

  <input type = "text" onChange = {this.nameHandler} value = {this.state.name}/>
```